# Where do you buy your Microsoft software licenses?

Tags: licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

Our company needs to buy Microsoft software Licenses for our project soon and I there are so many places to buy I don't know where to trust.

We need Windows Server 2008 Standard, and SQL Server 2008 Standard.

We are in China but the prices here are ridiculous. We could buy from the US.

We need 5 CALs. Buying for business.

Comment: China doesn't apply the Copyright law. Probably that's what made you think the prices are ridiculous. You can buy fake-licensed any version of Windows with 2$(!). Microsoft lowers the prices itself to compete with these 2$ed Windows which makes the prices REALLY ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

Just contact any reseller. Prices in china will seriously NOT be ridiculous - I doubt you will save buying in the US. Anyhow, any larger US resller rwill love to answer you.

How many licenses do you need and "what for" (i.e. are normal licenses applicable or do you fall under a special program)?

Answer (score 0):

Prices should be same. Also define for what purpose you wish you buy the license ?  NGO, Education or Business ??

you can go to any reseller site, who is Microsoft Gold partner certified.

Comment: Prices vary by region, I work for a Gold Partner and can lookup pricing info.